# Any sample C# project that highlights separate data access layer (using EF) to business logic layer

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm interested in having a look at a small sample project that would highlight a good technique to separate data access layer (using Entity Framework) to business logic layer.  In C# would be good.

That is, it would highlight how to pass data between the layer without coupling them.  That is, the assumption here is not to use the EF classes in the Business Logic layer, and how to achieve this low coupling, but minimizing plumbing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following examples
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399182.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sample_entity_framework.aspx 
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_linq/article.php/c15489/ADONET-Entity-Framework-Tutorial-and-Basics.htm 
http://adonetsamples.codeplex.com/